# Onesided Fourier Inversion formula

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

I am trying to understand Lacey's proof of  Carleson's theorem, which can be found here (https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0307008.pdf).
But I face problems even in the beginning. He is using  a so called ''one sided inversion Formular'' to define the Carleson operator for all $f \in L^2(R)$, namely in the following way:
\begin{align*}
\mathcal{C}f (x) = \sup_{N} \left| \int_{-\infty}^N \hat{f}(\zeta) e^{i x \zeta} \mathrm{d}\zeta\right| 
\end{align*}
where $\hat{f}$ is the Fourier transform.
I don't get why the integral should exist.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I didn't look at the paper, but what could be meant is to interpret the integral as $\mathcal{F}^{-1}(1_{(-\infty,N)} \cdot \widehat{f})(x)$, which is a well-defined $L^2$ function; then $\mathcal{C} f (x)$ would be well-defined a.e. at least.